# Read XML File Node

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to parse xml file using axios and jsonDataFromXml. I have no idea how to get the children nodes. My question here is how to read xml data to json object? My xml data format is as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dates>
  <Event>
  <Date>10/25/2022</Date>
  <Description>Priority Registration</Description>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Date>11/1/2022</Date>
    <Description>Open Registration</Description>
  </Event>
</Dates>
```

my reactjs code:

```
await axios
  .get(XMLData, {
    "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
  })
  .then((response) => {
    const jsonDataFromXml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(response.data);
    console.log("Your xml file as string", response.data);
    this.setState({Event:jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName("Event")});
    console.log("data", this.state.Event);
  });
```

};

I am trying to extract the xml data to  Event object array, with Date and Description fields. Right now it returns the format as below:

```
    Array [ {…}, {…} ]
0: Object { name: "Event", attributes: {}, children: (2) […], … }
attributes: Object {  }
children: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
0: Object { name: "Date", attributes: {}, value: "10/25/2022", … }
1: Object { name: "Description", attributes: {}, value: "Priority Registration", … }
length: 2
```

I want to retrieve the Object {Date, Description} only. Please advise! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my xml file to this format:

```
 <Dates>
  <Event Date="10/25/2022" Description="Spring Priority Registration" />
  <Event Date="11/1/2022" Description="Spring Open Registration" />
 </Dates>
```

Then read the data from the attributes and solve the problem. I still cannot figure out how to read the data as children.